# Attribute href not allowed on element button at this point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with a button and the W3C validation;
my code:

```
<button class="carousel-control left m-btn icn-only" href="#carousel_fade_2" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></button>
```

error w3c: Attribute href not allowed on element button at this point.

Any solution?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`href` is not a valid attribute of the [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element. A valid way would be to use a `data-*` attribute if you want to keep that value along with the button. For example:

```
<button
    class="carousel-control left m-btn icn-only"
    data-href="#carousel_fade_2"
    data-slide="prev">
```

If you want the browser to go to an anchor when clicking the button, you can use JavaScript to obtain the `data-href` value and update `window.location.href` with it, or you can use an [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) element instead, for which [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href) is a valid attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are used to submit forms. If you want to link somewhere, use an anchor:

```
<a href="#carousel_fade_2">
```

You can apply CSS to make it look like a button if you like.

Comment: Buttons can be used for many things, including wiping out data from a form and launching JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

href attricute is not used in the button element.

href is used in

`<a href="">`LinkName`</a>`

or you can try this

`<a href=""><button>` Button text `</button></a>`

hope this helps :)

Comment: Exchanging an invalid attribute for invalid markup (a button can't be a descendant of an A element) isn't a good idea.

Comment: yeah.. but just telling the possiblity

Comment: It's not a possibility, a button in an A element **is invalid**. Browsers will likely move the button outside the A to create a valid DOM.